# Why does cudaMemGetInfo report a change in the total amount of device memory?

Tags: c++, cuda

When I run the following piece of code the reported total amount of memory on my GPU changes (according to `cudaMemGetInfo` anyway). This behavior is not mentioned in the documentation for `cudaMemGetInfo`, which says that `total` should contain the total amount of memory on my device that can be allocated (which cannot change without putting a different GPU in my system right?). Can somebody explain why this is happening? It does not seem to happen when I don't call `cudaMallocManaged`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void printStats()
{
    size_t free, total;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total);
    std::cout << "free:  " << free << "\ntotal: " << total << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Before memory allocation
    printStats();

    int N = 1;
    float *x, *y;
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

    // After memory allocation.
    printStats();

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);

    // After freeing the memory.
    printStats();

    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
free:  94383273356630
total: 20
free:  5661994326
total: 4
free:  140729276827856
total: 94383273355680
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the word `free` as the name of a variable, but I don't think its the issue here.  What happens when you run your code with `cuda-memcheck`?  Are any errors reported?

Comment: @RobertCrovella No errors are reported, `ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors`.

Comment: Okay, it seems the problem has something to do with the selected device cudaGetDeviceCount() gives changed values each time as well.

Comment: Okay `cuda-memcheck` produced no errors but `cudaGetLastError()` returns 35 which seems to mean that the CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version whatever that means. Trying to fix that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when your CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version this sort of undefined behavior happens. For anyone else running into this problem I recommend checking the output of `cudaGetLastError()` that's how I discovered what the problem was.

I fixed it by downgrading my CUDA version to 10.1 since that was the newest version my driver supports. (You can check your CUDA and driver version using the `nvidia-smi` tool).